# How to sync row id of list adapter and cursor

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a database and I populate it in a listview using a list adapter. When I delete any row from the listview, the id of the next row doesnt change. For eg, if I have rows with id from 1 to 8 and i delete the 7th row, the new row id's are 1,2,3,4,5,6,8. But in the database, the row ids are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.
How can I sync these two so that I can access the correct element from the database using the onclick event of ListView?

Comment: which adaptor are you using? CursorAdaptor? custom with BaseAdaptor?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided information is not clear enough.You are deleting a row of id 7 from list view and your table has both 7 th and 8 th row.so still you have all the information you need.If you delete information from database table too then you will delete the row with id 7.still you don't have any problem.You can access row from table according to your list item id.

So may be you are messing with list item position and list item id.Consider id not the position of the item.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was talking about list item position. Actually I want to search a query in this list. From the cursor that I get after search, i use cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow (String ColumnID). But the value obtained is not synced with that entry of my database. And this happens whenever i delete any entry from the list.

Comment: while populating list, set list item id according to table row id.So you can retrieve actual id from the list item and delete the row with the id.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the following to update your ListView :

```
cursor.requery();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```